# How to enable internet access in the default switch of hyper-V?

Tags: networking, hyper-v

The most obvious solution was to check if internet access was available in the bridged mode and it's working fine. But using the default switch in Hyper-V i'm unable to access the internet. I need my hyper-V VM(Kali) to be in NAT mode itself. After some intense googling i found that internet access is not available in the default switch of hyper-V. But i did find a post in a forum where they seemed to be having internet access in the default switch itself. The most common solution i found in the internet was to change the metric value in the network adapter of the guest VM. But this can only be used if the guest VM is windows.

I tried setting the IP and DNS as automatically assigned in my host windows default switch network adapter. Tried setting the gateway as my host VM ipaddress to see if the issue was due to DNS resolution. Is there anyway to enable internet in the default switch mode?

Comment: the default switch does allow internet access, there's something wrong with your setup. Normally, it will just work. Messing with it's IP settings will make things worse. If you're using a wireless NIC, make sure you have the latest drivers.

Answer (score 2):

I have done a test in my lab and you could achieve you goal by attached screenshot of detailed steps.

[image]

For more details, please refer to this article from Microsoft [Set up a NAT network](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/setup-nat-network)

Comment: I configured the IPv4 address for the new NAT switch as 192.168.0.69 but the IP assigned to the guest VM in hyper-V was found to be 192.168.1.7. Although shortly after the VM got disconnected from the NAT switch and is not able to reconnect.. Switch doesn't get disconnected in the Bridged mode. I tried to switch back to bridged and then to NAT. Still gets disconnected from the switch in VM. I seemed to be facing this same issue yesterday when i tried to create a new NAT switch in the VM.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes in addition to creating Internal virtual switch and NAT using following commands:

```
New-VMSwitch -SwitchName "NAT-Switch" -SwitchType Internal
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 192.168.200.1 -PrefixLength 24 -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (NAT-Switch)"
New-NetNAT -Name "NAT-Network" -InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix 192.168.200.0/24
```

it may be necessary to also review your ExternalAddresses on the newly configured NAT.
Checkout:

```
Get-NetNatExternalAddress
```

If you get loopback address or other internal non-routable addresses, removing them with following command allows NAT to route traffic through proper network adatper:

```
Remove-NetNatExternalAddress -ExternalAddressID <ID>
```

Once I removed all but one ExternalAddress my VMs outgoing connections started to work properly.